# after aging server RAM upgrade - no boot?

Tags: boot

Its a cobbled together server so I wont go into hardware specifics, except that the motherboard is an Asus P58-E.

Upon booting the machine the CPU Fan speed moves in time with the flashing LEDs.  (The case mounted power LED and all three keyboard LEDs)  There is no BIOS error code.

I have tried

- Another power supply
- Booting on cardboard
- Booting with nothing connected except the speaker

Unsure what to try next.... any help appreciated,

Further information added: The machine does not POST, there is no way I can access the BIOS as the screen never comes out of mode 2.

Comment: Have you tried removing the RAM upgrade and sticking back in the old ones ?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out to be a blown capacitor on the motherboard.  The server was never rebooted - perhaps once or twice a year in its life.  I have read that capacitors are more likely to blow after a cold boot - so perhaps we were living on borrowed time.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Congrats on fixing it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with the RAM you currently have in the machine, make sure that the RAM you have is compatible. Don't just look at the DDR version. Look at the MHz to make sure that they match up. I have noticed in some servers at the datacenter that I work at don't like certain MHz even though they could just down grade the MHz.

If you checked the RAM and there is no issue, I would go into BIOS and see if there is a memory test that you can perform to make sure that every stick is good to the computer.

If this still doesn't show the issue, I would pull one stick of RAM out at a time and boot the server up until I found a change in behavior.

-Good Luck

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot boot the machine - even with no memory installed.  I cannot access the bios and the machine produces no beeps.

Comment: I would  do the third option that I provided than. But it doesn't sound like a RAM issue. Are there mother board lights on?

Comment: The 3rd option being booting with various configurations of memory?  I have done this, down to no memory.  And reset the CMOS at each stage.

Comment: The power led on the motherboard is on - and constant, unlike all other LEDs (case pwr led, keyboard) which blink

Comment: To rule out that it is a RAM issue, rip out the RAM and leave it empty, or put in the old RAM. Then let me know your results.

Comment: Hi David - I have tried to boot with all possible configurations of RAM.  No bios beeps, no difference.

Comment: I know it is a stretch, but you don't have another motherboard laying around that is compatible do you? We have ruled out the RAM issue, It could be back-plain, motherboard, CPU. Does a HDD light come on at all?

Comment: Im about there to be honest.  Time to scrounge a similiar enough motherboard to not require a reinstall.  Will update once I find one.........

Comment: There are no HDDs connected for a light to come - I have disconnected everything except the motherboard speaker.

Comment: I would have to say motherboard, but I'm not 100% sure. I don't know how it could be anything else if nothing is on the motherboard except a speaker and your not even getting BIOS. Let me know the progress. I am very interested. -Good Luck.

Comment: What CPU are you using? It's a slim possibility that the BIOS revision does not support the CPU.

Comment: I didnt change the CPU or BIOS revision, been running happily for a year or more.

Comment: I'm going to agree it's almost certainly just the board then.  Have you checked the power supply?  That's the only other likely culprit (beyond a really nasty CPU failure which is incredibly unlikely out of the blue like this)

Comment: Aye, I swapped out the PSU with another - same symptons.  The board seems fried, all capacitors look good.